# how do I redirect to the flask blueprint parent?

Tags: python, flask

Suppose i have the following structure:

```
/root/user/login
```

I do the login in a blueprint:

```
  app.register_blueprint(login_blueprint,url_prefix=prefix('/user'))
```

I can redirect to ".index":

```
@login_blueprint.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #### this redirects me to '/root/user/'
        redirect_to_index= redirect(url_for('.index'))
        response = current_app.make_response(redirect_to_index)
        # do the log in
     return response

    redirect_to_index=redirect(url_for('.index'))

    response = current_app.make_response(redirect_to_index)
```

The redirect brings me to `/root/user`:

```
redirect(url_for('.index'))
```

But how to get to `/root` (which is up relative to the current url (`..`)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pass `url_for` the name of the endpoint function for `/root/`.

For example, if you have:

```
@app.route('/root/')
def rootindex():
    return "this is the index for the whole site."
```

elsewhere in your app, you can do:

```
redirect(url_for('rootindex'))
```

To cause a redirect here. When you put a `.` in front of the string you pass to `url_for`, that tells it to look for an endpoint in the current blueprint. By leaving the `.` off, you tell it to look for a endpoint in the `app`

Comment: I think the question was asking if there is a relative method for doing so, not just a static way-- so if you have a blueprint stacked three deep (grandparent -> parent -> child) how could you relatively call the parents root function from the child (assuming your naming methods are the same) without mentioning the parent directly by name.

Comment: And just to answer my own question-- you can't currently nest blueprints, though it's something that's being looked into.

Comment: Indeed it would be nice to refer to a path relative to the parent of a blueprint. But this fixes it for me for now.